# 'Killed' after curl | tee

Tags: linux, bash, centos, kill, tee

I have centos image in virtualbox. When I do `curl [url] | tee -a [file]` where `[url]` is the url for a large file, the system start to kill all new proccesses and I get `Killed` answer in console for any command but `kill` and `cd`. How can I disable OOM daemon?

Answer (score 0):

The OOM Killer is your friend, why would you want to disable it? When the system is running out of memory, the kernel must start killing processes in order to stay operational. So lets be honest, you need the OOM Killer.

Instead, you might consider configuring the OOM Killer with some configuration that suits your needs; yet your current problems may persist.

In the light of the facts, it may be better to implement a more efficient way of doing these tasks you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like "your friend", the OOM killer, to kill innocent processes, a short answer is:

```
sysctl -w vm.overcommit_memory=2
```

More verbose answers and recommended reading:

- [Effects of configuring vm.overcommit_memory](https://serverfault.com/a/510857/226467)
- [How to disable the oom killer in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35791623/2413201)
- [Turn off the Linux OOM killer by default?](https://serverfault.com/a/194630/226467)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to store the response in a temporary file then using cat to further process the response.

```
curl [url] > curl_repsponse_temp_file
...
```